# Does ES6 const affect garbage collection?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, constants, ecmascript-6

In Kyle Simpson's new title, *You don't know JS: ES6 and beyond*, I find the following snippet:

> WARNING Assigning an object or array as a constant means that value will not be able to be garbage collected until that constant’s lexical scope goes away, as the reference to the value can never be unset. That may be desirable, but be careful if it’s not your intent!

(Excerpt From: Simpson, Kyle. “You Don’t Know JS: ES6 & Beyond.” O'Reilly Media, Inc., 2015-06-02. iBooks. 
This material may be protected by copyright.)

As far as I can see, he doesn't expand on this, and 10 minutes on Google turns up nothing. Is this true, and if so, what does "the reference to the value can never be unset" mean *exactly*? I have got into the habit of declaring variables that won't be changed as `const`, is this a bad habit in real concrete performance/memory terms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there are no performance implications. This note refers to the practise of helping the garbage collector (which is rarely enough needed) by "unsetting" the variable:

```
{
    let x = makeHeavyObject();
    window.onclick = function() {
        // this *might* close over `x` even when it doesn't need it
    };
    x = null; // so we better clear it
}
```

This is obviously not possibly to do if you had declared `x` as a `const`.

The lifetime of the variable (when it goes out of scope) is not affected by this. But if the garbage collector screws up, a constant will always hold the value it was initialised with, and prevent that from being garbage-collected as well, while a normal variable might no more hold it.

Comment: Can you elaborate perhaps on "if the garbage collector screws up"? Does that happen? Is it only in rare, complex situations?

Comment: Clever garbage collectors realize that `x` is not needed in the `onclick` function, and wipe it. Not so clever ones won't. It the closure setup is complex, this is more likely to happen. Afaik, this is very rare, and most often the values are not large enough to be significant. Also, even if it does happen, you still had to do this `= null` thing - which you don't anyway, so there's no difference from using `const`.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is inaccurate. See my answer posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686412/does-es6-const-affect-garbage-collection/38318597#38318597

Comment: @KyleSimpson: Where's the difference between `someCoolNumbers` in your answer and `x` in mine? The point that you (obviously) cannot explicitly nullify a `const` is the same.

Comment: @Bergi- The difference is that you claimed that this case -- "rarely needed" -- is some corner niche case that would only happen with a naive GC that didn't see that `x` wasn't needed. In my type of example, which is actually pretty common IME, `someCoolNumbers` is legitimately closed over in both functions, so naive GC or not, it's absolutely going to be kept around in the closure. If that module survives a long time, you might very well want to free up the memory holding the big array much earlier than when the module's scope itself is GCd.

Comment: @KyleSimpson: Sure, if the function closes over `x` (and there exists some point from which on calls to the function don't need `x` any more) helping the garbage collector is advisable even when the GC is not naive. But I still consider such situations to occur only rarely, most of the time the closure itself is collected anyway or the value is not large so that there is no memory leak that actually *required* the nullification.

Comment: @Bergi- you said "there are no performance implications." I definitely assert that there are, given the context (which I wrote the note) that I have cases where I indeed want to affect the GC by letting it run earlier for some value. I understand you think that's rare, but it's provably not never and also provably not some niche naive GC "bug" either. My answer down below, which I believe you downvoted, was pointing out that your assertion and mine are in fact qualitatively different.

Comment: @KyleSimpson: In such cases I'd say the performance implication is because the `null` assignment is missing, not because the variable was declared `const` :-) No, I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: @Bergi- The only reason the `null` assignment is missing (aka impossible) is if you use `const`. :) one clearly follows from the other.

Comment: @KyleSimpson: The more likely reason it was missing is that the author forgot it… and had he not forgotten it, he'd have made the `const` a `let`. Or it might not be missing, throw an exception on `const` assignment, blow up the application - and there's no more memory that could leak :-P

Answer (score 27):

> WARNING Assigning an object or array as a constant means that value
> will not be able to be garbage collected until that constant’s lexical
> scope goes away, as the reference to the value can never be unset.
> That may be desirable, but be careful if it’s not your intent!

That note sounds a bit more of a warning than is necessary (perhaps even a bit silly) and tries to make some sort of special case out of this situation.

With a `const` variable declaration, you can't assign to the variable something little like `""` or `null` to clear its contents.  That's really the only difference in regard to memory management.  Automatic garbage collection is not affected at all by whether it is declared `const` or not.

So, if you would like to be able to change the contents of the variable in the future for any reason (including to manually remove a reference to something to allow something to be garbage collected sooner), then don't use `const`.  This is the same as any other reason for using or not using `const`.   If you want to be able to change what the variable contains at any time in the future (for any reason), then don't use `const`.  This should be completely obvious to anyone who understand what `const` is for.

Calling out garbage collection as a special case for when not to use `const` just seems silly to me.  If you want to be able to clear the contents of a variable, then that means you want to modify the variable so duh, don't use `const`.  Yes, manually enabling garbage collection on a large data structure that might be caught in a lasting scope/closure is one reason that you might want to change the variable in the future.  But, it's just one of millions of reasons.  So, I repeat one more time.  If you ever want to change the contents of the variable for any reason in the future, then don't declare it as `const`.

The garbage collector itself doesn't treat a `const` variable or the contents it points to any different than a `var` or `let` variable.  When it goes out of scope and is no longer reachable, its contents will be eligible for garbage collection.

`const` has a number of advantages.  It allows the developer to state some intent that the contents this variable points to are not to be changed by code and may allow the runtime to make some optimizations because it knows the contents of the variable cannot be changed.  And, it prevents rogue or accidental code from ever changing the contents of that variable.  These are all good things when used in an appropriate case.  In general, you SHOULD use `const` as much as practical.

---

I should add the even some `const` data can still be reduced in size and make the majority of its contents available for garbage collection.  For example, if you had a really large 100,000 element array of objects (that you perhaps received from some external http call) in a const array:

```
const bigData = [really large number of objects from some API call];
```

You can still massively reduce the size of that data by simply clearing the array which potentially makes the large number of objects that was in the array eligible for garbage collection if nothing else had a reference to them:

```
bigData.length = 0;
```

Remember, that `const` prevents assignment to that variable name, but does not prevent mutating the contents that the variable points to.

You could do the same thing with other built-in collection types such as `map.clear()` or `set.clear()` or even any custom object/class that has methods for reducing its memory usage.

Comment: +1 for "silly"                                                                                               :-)

Comment: I accepted the other answer as it addressed my concern more directly but thanks very much!

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686412/does-es6-const-affect-garbage-collection/38318597#38318597

Comment: @KyleSimpson - What is inaccurate about this answer?  The question here is about `const` variables.  The answer you link discusses closures.  This question anticipates GC with closures in several ways, including the last two sentences.  But, bottom line - if you want to assign to the variable, don't make it `const`.  If you don't need to assign to it and want it protected, make it `const`.  Not any more complicated than that.

Comment: @KyleSimpson - `const` by itself does not change garbage collection at all.  If you wanted to manually remove a reference that a variable points to, then don't make that variable `const`.

Comment: @jfriend00- Your statement here is self-contradictory. Of course `const` affects GC... indirectly... because you're unable to free up a reference by unsetting it.

Comment: @KyleSimpson - The contents a variable points to will be garbage collected at exactly the same moment, whether the variable is declared with `const` or with `var`.  If you would like to modify the contents of that variable at any time in the future for whatever reason, then don't use `const`.

Comment: @jfriend00- you don't have any idea what you're talking about. A value (like an object/array) referenced by a `var`-declared variable can be unreferenced (by reassigning the variable) in which case it can be GCd quickly, even if the parent scope stays around (which it might). That same value referenced by a `const` declared variable cannot be unreferenced (because it can't be reassigned), which means the GC cannot happen on that value until the parent scope goes away.

Comment: @KyleSimpson - Do you think the GC treats a variable any different if it's `const` or `var`?  Yes, you the programmer must do things differently with `const` or `var`, but not the GC.  And, yes if you would like to set a variable to null sometime in the future to make something eligible for GC, then don't use `const`.  Duh.  My 2nd paragraph of my answer states that already. Any, what part of my previous comment do you think is wrong?  FYI, I disagree with you, but I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 - GC doesn't work on variables at all. It operates on **values**. In this case, arrays/objects that are **referenced** by variables. If you have a **value** you want GCd, and that value is referenced by a `const` declared variable, you cannot unset the reference and therefore it cannot be GCd. So clearly, `const` affects the ability for a **value** to be GCd because `const` creates a non-reassignable reference to that value. That will have the affect of preventing GC.

Comment: @jfriend00 - pretty much every part of your answer is wrong, because you continue to assert that the presence or absence of a `const` declaration as opposed to a `var` declaration will not have any effect on GC. It will. Plain and simple.

Comment: @KyleSimpson - This is my last note to you.  `const` ONLY affects your ability to modify the variable manually - period.  Just like any other variable, modifying it can change active references and can have an impact on whether something is eligible for GC or not.  So, if you use `const`, then you can't modify the variable and give up your chance to manually affect GC.  Left on their own, a `const` variable at the top of a function will be GCed at exactly the same moment as a `var` variable at the top of the function.  The garbage collector doesn't care what kind of variable it is.

Comment: @jfriend00 - "So, if you use const, then you can't modify the variable and give up your chance to manually affect GC". THANK YOU. You finally admitted what I kept saying you were wrong about. `const` absolutely does affect your ability to, as you call it, "manually affect GC". Sheesh.

Comment: >  "It allows the developer to state some intent that the contents this variable points to are not to be changed by code"
Only for primitive data structure, which is pretty rare in regular code execution. I'd say if there is no actual runtime optimization I can't see the point of using `const` after all...

Answer (score 13):

That note in my book was referring to cases like this, where you'd like to be able to manually make a value GC'able earlier than the end of life of its parent scope:

```
var cool = (function(){
   var someCoolNumbers = [2,4,6,8,....1E7]; // a big array

   function printCoolNumber(idx) {
      console.log( someCoolNumbers[idx] );
   }

   function allDone() {
      someCoolNumbers = null;
   }

   return {
      printCoolNumber: printCoolNumber,
      allDone: allDone
   };
})();

cool.printCoolNumber( 10 ); // 22
cool.allDone();
```

The purpose of the `allDone()` function in this silly example is to point out that there are times when you can decide you are done with a large data structure (array, object), even though the surrounding scope/behavior may live on (via closure) indefinitely in the app. To allow the GC to pick up that array and reclaim its memory, you unset the reference with `someCoolNumbers = null`.

If you had declared `const someCoolNumbers = [...];` then you would be unable to do so, so that memory would remain used until the parent scope (via the closure that the methods on `cool` have) goes away when `cool` is unset or itself GCd.

## Update

To make absolutely clear, because there's a lot of confusion/argument in some comment threads here, this is my point:

`const` absolutely, positively, undeniably has an effect on GC -- specifically, the ability of a value to be GCd manually at an earlier time. If the value is referenced via a `const` declaration, you cannot unset that reference, which means you cannot get the value GCd **earlier**. The value will only be able to be GCd when the scope is torn down.

If you'd like to be able to manually make a value eligible for GC earlier, while the parent scope is still surviving, you'll have to be able to unset your reference to that value, and you cannot do that if you used a `const`.

Some seem to have believed that my claim was `const` prevents any GC ever. That was never my claim. Only that it prevented earlier manual GC.

Comment: Bottom line - if you want to assign to the variable, don't make it `const`. If you don't need to assign to it and want it protected, make it const. Not any more complicated than that.  You're just defining one case where you might actually want to assign to it so don't make it `const` in that case.  I stand by my statement that making something `const` does  not change its garbage collection in any way.  It does affect whether you can assign to it so if you wanted to assign something to it in order to get rid of what you had assigned to it previously, then don't make it `const`.

Comment: @jfriend00- Referencing something with `const` absolutely changes its ability to be garbage collected, because it affects whether you can free up that thing for GC.

Comment: It affects your ability to manually release a reference to it - yes - duh you can't modify a `const` variable.  As I've said about 5 times.  If you intend to change the value of the variable in the future for ANY reason, then don't use `const`.  Otherwise, it is a great feature.  Left by themselves, a `const` variable and `var` variable at the top of a function will be garbage collected at exactly the same time.

Comment: @jfriend00 good grief, you still keep asserting that a variable gets GCd. It doesn't. **Values** get GCd. Variables that hold references to those values will prevent the GC. If those references can't be changed, the GC is prevented from happening earlier **if you want it to**. What I keep saying over and over is, "const affects GC because it prevents you from getting earlier GC, if you want it, for that value than scope teardown"

Comment: @KyleSimpson: If you want to nitpick, variables *are* garbage collected with their scopes (or earlier depending on engine optimisations). So you'd have to say "*`const` affects GC of the value because it prevents you from removing the reference, but it does not affect the GC of the variable*". Both you and jfriend are right here, just stop arguing now :-)

Comment: @KyleSimpson Thanks for replying to this, Kyle. I understand the issue fully now, but when I read the book I really didn't. I don’t usually have a hard time understanding your writing – quite the opposite in fact – so maybe it would be worth expanding on this in the next edition/update to the book?

Comment: @jfriend00 it appears this boils down to how frequently you need to create objects with (large) data which the object itself outlives—necessitating a nudge to help the garbage collector. I've literally never written or seen any such code, but Kyle does seem to code in a unique style :)

Comment: @AdamRackis - No, it doesn't boil down to how frequently you do that.  It's not like you always use one or the other based on your usual tendencies.  If you want to be able to manually change or clear what a variable points to, then don't use `const` to declare it because `const` is an explicit instruction to the JS interpreter to disallow changing the variable.  Otherwise, if you want to protect that specific variable from modification, use `const`.  It's that simple.  It doesn't depend upon your "tendencies".  Each variable should be evaluated separately for what your intentions are.

Comment: @jfriend00 no I understand all that. I guess my point was: if you never need to manually free a variable, then const will never affect garbage collection. Tho you have a point too: if you need to manually free a variable, you'd never ever declare it with const, so in that respect too, `const` would never affect garbage collection.

Answer (score 8):

The way garbage collectors (GC) work is when something is referenced by nothing ("cannot be reached"), the GC can safely say that something isn't used anymore and reclaim the memory used by that something.

Being able to replace the value of a variable allows one to remove a reference to the value. However, unlike `var`, `const` cannot be reassigned a value. Thus, one can't remove that constant from referencing the value.

A constant, like a variable, can be reclaimed when the constant goes "out of scope", like when a function exits, and nothing inside it forms a closure.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that Mr Simpson was only referring to a _manual_ unsetting of a variable no longer being possible? As @Bergi says in his answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had to accept the other really as it more directly answered my question but all the answers including yours were great!