# JS: can a var/object declared as const be deleted

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Newbie question:

Can const objects be deleted or overwritten in js?

```
const a = function myFunc(){}; // some code to delete 'a' and 'myFunc()' here.
```

Comment: I'm asking both questions.

Comment: @davidLeak Why do you think that is called "deleting"?

Comment: I'm also referring to const in a global scope.

Comment: may i free up the memory for a if const a; ?

Comment: sorry const a = "string or something else here".

Comment: @davidLeak Freeing up? Garbage collectors will do that for you.

Comment: Maybe see also [Does ES6 const affect garbage collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31686412/1048572)

Comment: fyi - const a = {}; var b = new a; a = 33; I just changed the const 'a' back to a var.

Comment: sorry... const work = {}; var dd = work; dd = 99; work = 22; it returns 22 and should return what ever you set it to however it's default will be an undefined object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A downside to using `const` is that you cannot clear the variable at will (`const` prevents it from being changed in any way).

If the variable is not in the global scope, then the garbage collector will take care of it when it goes out of scope.  If it is in the global scope, then you cannot get rid of it.  The work-around is to stop using `const` for variables that you wish to modify.

Properties of an object, assigned to a `const` variable are not affected by the `const` declaration as the `const` delcaration affects the variable, not the the contents that it points to.  You can use `Object.freeze()` or `Object.seal()` if you want to affect properties of an object.

Comment: thank you, that was helpful.  I understand now.

Comment: follow up question.  Does that also include it's properties and methods?  may I modify those?

Comment: @davidLeak - it takes minutes to just try this stuff yourself.  In the current version of Chrome, `const` does not prevent the assigning of properties to an object pointed to by a variable declared with `const`.  It just prevents the assignment to the variable itself.  This is probably because the object isn't const, just the variable.  `Object.freeze()` and `Object.seal()` affect the properties of an object.

Comment: If I tried it myself, I wouldn't have just learned about Object.freeze() and Object.seal(). :)  Thanks again.

Comment: fyi - const a = {}; var b = new a; a = 33; I just changed the const 'a' back to a var.

Comment: @davidLeak - When I try those three statements in Chrome, I just see the second one throw an error because `a` is not a function and the third one never executes and `a` is not changed.  I'm not sure what you were showing there?

Comment: const work = {}; var dd = work; dd = 99; work = 22; it returns 22 and should return what ever you set it to however it's default will be an undefined object.

Comment: @davidLeak - What does that show?  Please describe your comments rather than just posting some code.  If you're typing this into the console, you are being misled as the console is reporting something other than the value of `work`.  When I run that code in a jsFiddle, the value of `work` is not modified in any way.  I would appreciate it if you make sure you've actually discovered something of consequence for `const` before sending me off testing something again.