# Removing object from array using hooks (useState)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have an array of objects. I need to add a function to remove an object from my array without using the "this" keyword.

I tried using `updateList(list.slice(list.indexOf(e.target.name, 1)))`. This removes everything but the last item in the array and I'm not certain why.

```
const defaultList = [
{ name: "ItemOne" },
{ name: "ItemTwo" },
{ name: "ItemThree" }]

const [list, updateList] = useState(defaultList);

const handleRemoveItem = e => {
    updateList(list.slice(list.indexOf(e.target.name, 1)))
}

return (
    {list.map(item => {
        return ( 
            <>
            <span onClick={handleRemoveItem}>x </span>
            <span>{item.name}</span>
            </>
        )}
    }
)
```

Expected behaviour: The clicked item will be removed from the list.
Actual behaviour: The entire list gets removed, minus the last item in the array.

Comment: For starters there is no `name` on a span. Do some basic debugging and see what `e.target.name` even is. Then...read the documentation for how `slice()` works as well as how `indexOf()` works. You have multiple problems in that method

Comment: You're right there's no name on a span. That's why the name refers to the item mapped from the array. Did you even read the post?

Comment: No it does not in the context you are using `onClick={handleRemoveItem}`. Did you inspect it inside the function?

Comment: @collinswade408 see my solution below. That should give you some insight on how to complete your solution and why your code does not work.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

First of all, the `span` element with the click event needs to have a `name` property otherwise, there will be no name to find within the `e.target`. With that said, `e.target.name` is reserved for form elements (input, select, etc). So to actually tap into the name property you'll have to use `e.target.getAttribute("name")`

Additionally, because you have an array of objects, it would not be effective to use `list.indexOf(e.target.name)` since that is looking for a `string` when you are iterating over objects. That's like saying find "dog" within `[{}, {}, {}]`

Lastly, `array.slice()` returns a new array **starting with the item at the index** you passed to it. So if you clicked the last-item, you would only be getting back the last item.

Try something like this instead using `.filter()`: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-brook-mct26)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const defaultList = [
    { name: "ItemOne" },
    { name: "ItemTwo" },
    { name: "ItemThree" }
  ];

  const [list, updateList] = useState(defaultList);

  const handleRemoveItem = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.getAttribute("name")
    updateList(l => l.filter(item => item.name !== name));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map(item => {
        return (
          <>
            <span name={item.name} onClick={handleRemoveItem}>
              x
            </span>
            <span>{item.name}</span>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: A `<span>` can't have a `name` attribute or properly.

Comment: @WillJenkins Sure it can, you just wouldn't be able to see it via `event.target.name`.

Comment: Check the spec, a `<span>` can't have a `name` https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/attributes.html

Comment: What if two elements have the same name value? It will remove both elements, @ChrisNgo

Answer (score 37):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do this in a one-liner:

```
const handleRemoveItem = name => {
    updateList(list.filter(item => item.name !== name))
}
```

Eta: you'll also need to pass the name of your item in your onClick handler:

```
{list.map(item => {
    return ( 
        <>
        <span onClick={() =>handleRemoveItem(item.name)}>x </span>
        <span>{item.name}</span>
        </>
    )}
```

Answer (score 26):

```
const defaultList = [
    { name: "ItemOne" },
    { name: "ItemTwo" },
    { name: "ItemThree" }
]

const [list, updateList] = useState(defaultList);

const handleRemoveItem = idx => {
    // assigning the list to temp variable
    const temp = [...list];

    // removing the element using splice
    temp.splice(idx, 1);

    // updating the list
    updateList(temp);
}

return (
    {list.map((item, idx) => (
      <div key={idx}>
        <button onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(idx)}>x </button>
        <span>{item.name}</span>
      </div>
    ))}

)
```

Comment: Doesn't the temp variable get left in memory after its done with this example? That wouldn't be good for large work loads.

Comment: @IanSmith any suggestions for that?

Comment: JavaScript collects its garbage as values go out of scope. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/31686412/1264804

Answer (score 2):

Small improvement in my opinion to the best answer so far

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const defaultList = [
    { name: "ItemOne" },
    { name: "ItemTwo" },
    { name: "ItemThree" }
  ];

  const [list, updateList] = useState(defaultList);

  const handleRemoveItem = (item) => {
    updateList(list.filter(item => item.name !== name));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map(item => {
        return (
          <>
            <span onClick={()=>{handleRemoveItem(item)}}>
              x
            </span>
            <span>{item.name}</span>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Instead of giving a name attribute we just send it to the handle function

Comment: got 2 small mistakes there I think. fix them to:
1) const handleRemoveItem = (name) => { ... // etc

2) onClick={()=>{handleRemoveItem(item.name)}}

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will do

```
let targetIndex = list.findIndex((each) => {each.name == e.target.name});
list.splice(targetIndex-1, 1);
```

We need to check name value inside object so use findIndex instead. then cut the object start from target index to 1 array after target index.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/williamgunawan22/pen/BXwOeG?editors=1111)

> From your comment your problem came from another part.

Change this view section

```
    return ( 
        <>
        <span onClick={() => handleRemoveItem(item) }>x </span>
        <span>{item.name}</span>
        </>
    )}
```

change function handleRemoveItem format

```
const handleRemoveItem = item => {
    list.splice(list.indexOf(item)-1, 1)
    updateList(list);
}
```

Comment: Best not to mutate original array

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this returns a typescript error `Argument of type '(each: { name: string; }) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {name: string; }, index: number, obj: { name: string;}[]) => boolean'.`

Comment: You can check the code pen. I think the issue in another part not this part;

Comment: I don't know why you use const because it's not editable.

Comment: The underlying problem now is `e.target.name` is undefined

Comment: Closer except splice() returns what was removed

Comment: Done. You can check it again.. Hope your problem gone!

Answer (score 1):

Redundant one liner - would not recommend as hard to test / type / expand / repeat / reason with

```
 <button onClick={() => setList(list.slice(item.id - 1))}
```

A version without exports:

```
 const handleDeleteItem = id => {
     const remainingItems = list.slice(id - 1)
     setList(remainingItems);
}
```

However I would consider expanding the structure of your logic differently by using helper functions in another file.

With that in mind, I made one example for filter and another for slice. I personally like the slice option in this particular use-case as it makes it easy to reason with. Apparently, it is also slightly more performant on larger lists if scaling (see references).

If using slice, always use slice not splice unless you have good reason not to do so as it adheres to a functional style (pure functions with no side effects)

```
// use slice instead of splice (slice creates a shallow copy, i.e., 'mutates' )
export const excludeItemFromArray = (idx, array) => array.slice(idx-1)

// alternatively, you could use filter (also a shallow copy)
export const filterItemFromArray = (idx, array) => array.filter(item => item.idx !== idx)
```

Example (with both options filter and slice options as imports)

```
import {excludeItemFromArray, filterItemFromArray} from 'utils/arrayHelpers.js'

const exampleList = [
    { id: 1, name: "ItemOne" },
    { id: 2, name: "ItemTwo" },
    { id: 3, name: "ItemThree" }
]

const [list, setList] = useState(exampleList);

const handleDeleteItem = id => {
  
    //excluding the item (returning mutated list with excluded item)
    const remainingItems = excludeItemFromArray(id, list)

    //alternatively, filter item (returning mutated list with filtered out item)
    const remainingItems = filterItemFromArray(id, list)

    // updating the list state
    setList(remainingItems);
}

return (
    {list.map((item) => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <button onClick={() => handleDeleteItem(item.id)}>x</button>
        <span>{item.name}</span>
      </div>
    ))}
)
```

References:

- Don't use index keys in maps: https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/
- Performance of slice vs filter: https://medium.com/@justintulk/javascript-performance-array-slice-vs-array-filter-4573d726aacb
- Slice documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice
- Functional programming style: [https://blog.logrocket.com/fundamentals-functional-programming-react/#:~:text=Functional%20programming%20codes%20are%20meant,computations%20are%20called%20side%20effects](https://blog.logrocket.com/fundamentals-functional-programming-react/#:%7E:text=Functional%20programming%20codes%20are%20meant,computations%20are%20called%20side%20effects).

Comment: These links have proved an interesting read!

Answer (score 0):

Using this pattern, the array does not jump, but we take the previous data and create new data and return it.

```
 const [list, updateList] = useState([
    { name: "ItemOne" },
    { name: "ItemTwo" },
    { name: "ItemThree" }
  ]);

     updateList((prev) => {
                return [
                    ...prev.filter((item, i) => item.name !== 'ItemTwo')
                ]
            })
```

Comment: To reduce the number of lines, you could remove the `return` statement like so: 
 `updateList((prev) => ([...prev.filter((item) => item.name !== 'ItemTwo')]))`

Answer (score -1):

This is because both [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/slice) and [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice) return an array containing the removed elements.

You need to apply a `splice` to the array, and **then** update the state using the method provided by the hook

```
const handleRemoveItem = e => {
    const newArr = [...list];
    newArr.splice(newArr.findIndex(item => item.name === e.target.name), 1)
    updateList(newArr)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The above did not work unfortunately, so i tried 
`const newArr= list.splice(list.indexOf(e.target.name, 1))
 updateList(newArr)` 
which gives me the same issue as my original post. :(

Comment: That's because the splice method is still returning an array of removed elements, even if you store it in a variable.

Comment: You can't use `indexOf()` on array of objects this way

Comment: Yeah, I just made a edit, I copy/pasted this part of the code from the question and didn't pay attention to the data structure.