# Animate Presence `exit` prop is not working with array elements

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm new to Framer Motion. I have a trouble with it.

I have an array of titles. I'm trying to animate them one by one. First fades in then fades out. It can be doable with `<AnimationPresence />` as far as I know. I did like that:

```
export default function Title() {

    const texts = [
        {text: "UNLEASH YOUR POWER", id: 1},
        {text: "SURRENDER TO YOUR FEELINGS", id: 2},
        {text: "RELEASE INNER BEAST", id: 3},
        {text: "EXPLORE PREDATOR SENSE", id: 4}
    ]

    const [list, updateList] = useState(texts)

    return <div className='title'>
        <AnimatePresence>
            {list.map((item, index, arr) => {
                updateList(arr.filter(jtem => jtem.text !== item.text))
                return <motion.span
                    key={item.id}
                    initial={{opacity: 0, scale: 0.5}}
                    animate={{opacity: 1, scale: 1}}
                    exit={{opacity: 0}}
                    transition={{
                        duration: 0.8,
                        delay: 0.5,
                        ease: [0, 0.71, 0.2, 1.01],
                        // repeat: Infinity
                    }}
                >
                    {item.text}
                </motion.span>
            })}
        </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
}
```

But, it's not working as expected. They're all animating in same time and never fade out. How could it be tackled?

Comment: How do you remove them?

Comment: `@Konrad` By `exit` prop

Comment: `exit` says what should happen when an element is deleted. But you don't have any code that would delete an element

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing object from array using hooks (useState)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57341541/removing-object-from-array-using-hooks-usestate)

Comment: Yes, I got it. But how I integrate removing function with Animation Presence?

Comment: I would be delightful if you could provide a code or sandbox.

Comment: Your current code should work. Just use state and delete an item

Comment: Updated the code. You mean like that?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-shape-hmgemf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It should work automatically. I did it already what you typed in sandbox.

Comment: Seems I make the question very difficult and irritating you.